# SELECT DISTINCT creates multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, distinct, where-clause

Complete SQL newbie so please be kind. I have the following statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tTMPO."OperationRecordID"
    , tTMPO."CasenoteNumber"
    , tTMPO."DateTimeBooked"
    , tSPPS."StartDate"
    , AEAdm."Visit Date"
    , AEAdm."Visit Time"
    , AEAdm."Episode Number"
    , AEAdm.[Visit Number]
FROM   
    (("TheatreLive"."dbo"."tblSPPlannedSession" tSPPS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "TheatreLive"."dbo"."tblTMPlannedOperation" tTMPO ON tSPPS."SessionRecordID" = tTMPO."SessionRecordID") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "TheatreLive"."dbo"."tblTMActualOperation" tTMAO ON tTMPO."OperationRecordID" = tTMAO."OperationRecordID") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "TheatreLive"."dbo"."cavAEAdmissions" AEAdm ON tTMAO."CasenoteNumber"=AEAdm."CRN" COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
WHERE 
    tSPPS."StartDate" < DateAdd(day, 2, AEAdm."Visit Date") 
    AND AEAdm."Visit Date" < tSPPS."StartDate"
```

I used the `DISTINCT` however notice that multiple rows for `OperationRecordID` are appearing when more than one episode number appears. I tried adding a `SELECT TOP 1` but the complete logic found in the `WHERE` clause would need to be added which ran exceptionally slowly.

The `WHERE` clause is there to narrow down the results set and so it is only looking for dates that are within 2 days of each other.

Essentially, for each distinct `OperationRecordID` I need both the latest episode number and if more than 1 visit number appears, then the highest visit number also. Both of these should be able to be selected with a `MAX` clause.

Thoughts?

Comment: `distinct` applies to the whole set, not any single column.

Comment: As @jpw said, this is expected. You probably want `group by`.

Comment: You need group by man

Comment: You also shouldn't use double quotes around your column names. I would advise against putting spaces in your column names and you don't need anything. The standard is to wrap your column names in [] when you have those dreaded spaces. You seem to have a mixture going on here.

Answer (score 0):

The DISTINCT keyword applies to all columns selected - not just the column it appears before. Sounds like you might need the Max function with a GROUP BY or, depending on how complex your criteria are, an inline table.

Something like

```
SELECT 
    tTMPO."OperationRecordID"
    , tTMPO."CasenoteNumber"
    , tTMPO."DateTimeBooked"
    , tSPPS."StartDate"
    , AEAdm."Visit Date"
    , AEAdm."Visit Time"
    , Max(AEAdm."Episode Number")
    , Max(AEAdm.[Visit Number])
FROM   
    (("TheatreLive"."dbo"."tblSPPlannedSession" tSPPS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "TheatreLive"."dbo"."tblTMPlannedOperation" tTMPO ON tSPPS."SessionRecordID" = tTMPO."SessionRecordID") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "TheatreLive"."dbo"."tblTMActualOperation" tTMAO ON tTMPO."OperationRecordID" = tTMAO."OperationRecordID") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "TheatreLive"."dbo"."cavAEAdmissions" AEAdm ON tTMAO."CasenoteNumber"=AEAdm."CRN" COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
WHERE 
    tSPPS."StartDate" < DateAdd(day, 2, AEAdm."Visit Date") 
    AND AEAdm."Visit Date" < tSPPS."StartDate" 
GROUP BY tTMPO."OperationRecordID"
    , tTMPO."CasenoteNumber"
    , tTMPO."DateTimeBooked"
    , tSPPS."StartDate"
    , AEAdm."Visit Date"
    , AEAdm."Visit Time"
```

Comment: Thanks @amcdermott - I got somewhere with doing something similar but I am still finding that I get multiple repeated rows so I discarded the group idea.

Comment: You would expect DISTINCT to return every unique combination of OperationRecordID, CaseNoteNumber, DateTimeBooked, StartDate, VisitDate, VisitTime. GROUP BY will do something similar - the difference being it is applied when performing aggregate functions. If fields are being duplicated its because there are different value in some rows and you probably want to see them. Why don't you explain your table structure and what you want your query to show and I can take a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code that @amcdermott with the following to try to eradicate the duplication that separate date and time fields seemed to be causing:

```
    SELECT 
    tTMPO.[OperationRecordID]
    , tTMPO.[CasenoteNumber]
    , tTMPO.[DateTimeBooked]
    , tSPPS.[StartDate]
/*    , AEAdm.[Visit Date]
    , AEAdm.[Visit Time]*/
    , MAX (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), AEAdm.[Visit Date], 112) 
  + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), AEAdm.[Visit Time], 108))) as Visit
    , MAX(AEAdm.[Episode Number]) as Epi#
    , MAX(AEAdm.[Visit Number]) as Visit#
FROM   
    ((TheatreLive.dbo.tblSPPlannedSession tSPPS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    TheatreLive.dbo.tblTMPlannedOperation tTMPO ON tSPPS.SessionRecordID = tTMPO.SessionRecordID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    TheatreLive.dbo.tblTMActualOperation tTMAO ON tTMPO.OperationRecordID = tTMAO.OperationRecordID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    TheatreLive.dbo.cavAEAdmissions AEAdm ON tTMAO.CasenoteNumber=AEAdm.CRN COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
WHERE 
    tSPPS.StartDate < DateAdd(day, 5, AEAdm.[Visit Date]) 
    AND AEAdm.[Visit Date] < tSPPS.StartDate 
GROUP BY tTMPO.OperationRecordID
    , tTMPO.CasenoteNumber
    , tTMPO.DateTimeBooked
    , tSPPS.StartDate
/*    , AEAdm.[Visit Date]
    , AEAdm.[Visit Time]
    , AEAdm.[Episode Number]*/
```

This works! Thanks everyone. Hopefully the code is a little cleaner also ;-) Told you I was a newbie.